# Converting MSB padding to LSB padding

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg and Vulkan for a video related project. The problem is that FFmpeg uses MSB padding for the 9, 10 and 12bit formats, whilst Vulkan accepts LSB padded pixel formats.

I am using the following code to convert from one another, but the performance is terrible (1 second per frame), which cannot be accepted for video playback.

```
if(paddingBits > 0) {
    //As padding bits are set to 0, using CPU words for the shifting should not affect the result
    assert(dstBuffers[plane].size() % sizeof(size_t) == 0);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < dstBuffers[plane].size(); i += sizeof(size_t)) {
        reinterpret_cast<size_t&>(dstBuffers[plane][i]) <<= paddingBits;
    }
}
```

Note that this code will be executed 1-4 times per frame (once per `plane`) and `dstBuffers[plane].size()` will be in the order of a couple of MegaBytes. `dstBuffers[plane]`'s data has an alignment greater than `size_t`'s, so I am not performing unaligned read/writes. Using a smaller type such as uint16_t makes it perform worse.

My question is if there is any standard function (or inside the FFmpeg library) which implements the same behavior in a fancy way so that the performance is not a concern. If not, is there a more efficient way to implement it?

Edit:`dstBuffers[plane]` stores `std::byte`-s and although is not of type `std::vector`, (it is a custom class) it is contiguous.

Comment: Did you verify that your compiler vectorized the code?

Comment: @Botje this testing has been done in debug mode, so probably the compiler is not vectorizing the code. However, I need this code to work also in debug mode, so simply turning on optimizations is not viable in this case.

Comment: Another option could be using 16bit formats on FFmpeg, so that padding gets done at the LSB. Sadly, codecs seem to not offer this option when negotiating

Comment: One approach could be to manually vectorize the loop using simd intrinsics, this should be fairly straightforward, I think.

Comment: Also, did you check the generated code for this function? Could running in debug mode add a bounds check somewhere or call a non-inlined function? That can cause the slowdown you mention if called a few million times per second.

Comment: @Botje All the call stack above of this code piece (operator[]) is marked as inline. However, it has an assertion for bound checking. Commenting it does not make a difference (strange?). For portability reasons, I rather not use SIMD intrinsics. I'll probably stick with swscale, although it is a bit OP for this problem, it will do the trick.

Comment: Just because it's marked inline does not mean that the compiler will do that in debug mode. I would check the generated code first.